# How to add Captcha in Contao CMS 3.5.9 form?

Tags: captcha, contao

I want to add ( Number + Character ) captcha for contao CMS 3.5.9. Anybody can suggest me which one extension is good and easy to implement?

Contao default form giving simple security question that i know but that would not useful to me i guess. i want to add Number + Character as in captcha.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [[recaptcha](https://contao.org/en/extension-list/view/recaptcha.html)]. There is also a newer version available on https://github.com/mrflory/contao-recaptcha, which you can install via the composer package management in Contao, or manually (it has no additional dependencies). There are some other alternative captcha extensions, however they are only compatible with Contao 2 and haven't been maintained over the years.

Alternatively you could try [Contao AntiSpam](http://rocksolidthemes.com/en/contao/plugins/honeypot-antispam).